# why didn't I get an error from perl when $v=false;

Tags: perl

On commandline I wrote:

```
perl -e '$v=false; if($v==true){print 1;}'
```

and instead of producing an error it returned "1"!

As I remember in past this returned an error to remind me that perl has no boolean type. anything changed in perl in the meantime? or did I remember incorrectly and this always was valid code?

Comment: https://perlmaven.com/barewords-in-perl. Always `use strict` and `use warnings`.

Comment: many thanks! I edited .bashrc and added `alias perl="perl -Mstrict -Mwarnings"`

Comment: Instead of aliasing `perl`, you can set `PERL5OPT` with the default options.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Without [strict](http://p3rl.org/strict), the bareword `false` is interpreted as the string (`'false'`). Using the numeric `==` numifies it to 0, and `"true"` as a number is zero, too.

[B::Deparse](http://p3rl.org/B::Deparse) shows it clearly:

```
$ perl -MO=Deparse -e '$v=false; if($v==true){print 1;}'
$v = 'false';
if ($v == 'true') {
    print 1;
}
```

[warnings](http://p3rl.org/warnings) would have warned you 4 times: twice  about the unquoted bareword, and twice about numeric comparison of strings.